# Don't have a build option in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I use Unity and when I write a script on the visual studio I don't have the build option and the system doesn't know to continue my word.

[image]

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: Did you open a solution? Or a file? Which version of VS do you use? Does it on default settings?

Comment: Usually unity compiles your code. Vs is just the editor

Comment: I seriously suggest you use other IDEs like Rider (https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/)

Answer (score 1):

Use F5 key or ctrl + F5 key to build your code on the go

Comment: you can also use ```ctrl+b``` and/or ```ctrl+shift+b```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I know what he means.

I had to go ASSETS --> OPEN c# project to see the BUILD option.  Otherwise when I double clicked a C# script file in the project it would open without intellisense and I couldn't build or see the "attach to unity" in the debugger.

Hope this helps someone else.